# CURRENT_RPC_CONTEXT.get() must not be null

Tags: corda

Written the Integration test case for testing Corda Flows through API class as:

```
val api=ProjectApi(mockNode1.rpcOps)
val message = "some input message"
val resp: Response=api.publishSSI(message)
assertEquals(resp.status, 201,"Failed to publish SSI")
```

But getting `CURRENT_RPC_CONTEXT.get() must not be null` exception while starting corda flow inside `api.publishSSI()` method.
what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the RPC client API to connect to the node. You can find more details here: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-clientrpc-api.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't test the API by manually constructing it in this way. When the API is set up, some additional context is passed in, which is lacking here.

Comment: Could you please suggest the way around?